# Angular 4 routing: Is it possible to add constraints to route parameters?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to match for a language in my routing service.
My problem is that the language needs to be first in my route.

For example:

/en/xxx

/fr/xxx

/en/yyy

/fr/yyy

Since I want to use this parameter i have added the following route

```
{ path: ':lang',  children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'xxx', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'xxx', component: x},
      {path: 'yyy', component: y}
]}
```

The issue is that everything matches :lang.

For example:

/abc/xxx

I would like to add constraints to this so that I can say that :lang can only be of type <'nl' | 'fr' | 'en' | 'de'>.

Now when I want to go to /robots.txt (which should show me the robots.txt file) it maps to :lang and sends me to "/robots.txt/xxx"

I have tried mapping every language separately but then i don't have access to the route parameter.

I have tried adding the robots.txt above but since it's a assets file, i don't know how to show it by adding a line in the routes.ts file.

I have tried adding an exception in the route guard but then I can't redirect to robots.txt since it just keeps mapping on the :lang parameter.

This is my current routes.ts file:

```
{path: '', redirectTo: '/xxx', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [LangGuard]},
{path: 'xxx', component: xxx, canActivate: [LangGuard]},
{path: 'yyy', component: yyy, canActivate: [LangGuard]},
{ path: ':lang', canActivate: [LangGuard], children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'xxx', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'xxx', component: x},
      {path: 'yyy', component: y}
]}
```

My LangGuard is pretty extensive but ill write a short version down:

```
Get route parameters
If parameter is "nl", "fr", "de" or "en"
then return true //do nothing
else router.navigate('/' + decideLanguage() + state.url) // redirect to new url
```

Maybe a little overview of what i want to achieve and what i am getting:

What i want

```
/ -> /en/xxx
/abc -> /en/xxx
/xxx -> /en/xxx
/yyy -> /en/yyy

/en/xxx -> ok
/fr/xxx -> ok
/de/xxx -> ok

/en/abc -> notfound

/abc/xxx -> notfound
/abc/yyy -> notfound


/robots.txt -> ok
```

What I have

```
/ -> /en/xxx
/abc -> /en/xxx
/xxx -> /en/xxx
/yyy -> /en/yyy

/en/xxx -> ok
/fr/xxx -> ok
/de/xxx -> ok

/en/abc -> notfound

/abc/xxx -> ok (WRONG)
/abc/yyy -> ok (WRONG)


/robots.txt -> /robots.txt/xxx (WRONG)
```

NOTE: I can't use redirectTo for the language because the language is selected according to the localstorage, thats why i am using the routeguard

If I need to add more information or you have some questions, feel free to ask and I will answer them to the best of my abilities.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would give a try to Angular [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher)
. With that you can define your own url matching function. IMHO The guards are more meant to check authentication, not to check if the route is valid or not.

**Here goes an example**:

*Routing*

```
export function checkLang(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  return url[0].path.startsWith('en') || url[0].path.startsWith('fr') || url[0].path.startsWith('de') || url[0].path.startsWith('nl') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}

export const routes = [  matcher: checkLang, component: TestComponent, children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'xxx', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'xxx', component: x},
      {path: 'yyy', component: y}
]}]
```

and then the *TestComponent*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: '<div>HELLO</div>'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('LANGUAGE: ' + this.route.snapshot.url[0].path); // here you get the language and you can act consequently 
  }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed coming close to what I am looking for! The only problem i have is that i would like to combine the matcher with the use of parameters. When i implement the code you suggested i get the following error: 

---invalid configuration of route ':lang': path and matcher cannot be used together ---

So I removed the path part, but i lose the parameter functionality

Comment: I have just updated the answer adding a component on which you can retrieve in a more manual way the language

Comment: Thank you, this will require some reworking for my current setup but I think this should work!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `canActivate` guard and use it to Programmatically ascertain that the `lang` route param is one of the four languages you mentioned.

Comment: Lets say that i would add this and it returns false when it's not one of the four languages... How can I make it match other routes? Does angular keep on matching untill a route works? I thought once a route was matched (route guard or not) it stayed there or went back to landingspage

Comment: Obviously all parameterized routes should be at the very end or it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Router cannot determine if the route is a param or a defined path. So keep all your static routes before the same and finally add the route guard for the language based route.

Comment: I haven't implemented this myself, but should work theoretically. Do spin up a stackblitz and try for yourself! You could update the question if it works so others can use the community wisdom :)

Comment: When i was looking into how to serve robots.txt. It said that angular automatically maps this route when it is located in the assets folder. This gets blocked by the mapping of language. I don't think this will change anything but I'll try it. I will update once i have tried.

Comment: Indeed but my main issue is that angular controlls the assets routes, and i don't know how to add it to my routes file so i have control over where it gets mapped to

Comment: Okay i have tried and implemented a new guard but when i return false, it just kicks me back to the root url instead of serving me an assets file

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer serves this purpose, worth mentioning that this is not flexible enough if one has a custom component for language not found for instance. Unless it is both sound and possible to navigate from inside the matching function of which I doubt. I think in that case the ideal is to have a container component just to do the check else navigate matching :lang with the rest loaded as children.

Routing

```
{
    path: ':lang',
        component: LanguageContainerComponent,
            children: [
                {
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'xxx', pathMatch: 'full' },
                { path: 'xxx', component: x },
                { path: 'yyy', component: y }
      }
    ]
},
{ path: 'languagenotfound', component: LanguageNotFoundComponent },
```

Component

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-language-container',
        template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
    })
    export class LanguageContainerComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(
            public route: ActivatedRoute,
            public router: Router
        ) { }


        ngOnInit() {
            // Do your checks here
            //  if fail
            this.router.navigate(['languagenotfound']);
        }
    }
```

In case you are using a library such as ngx-translate one may inject

```
private translate: TranslateService
```

and use

```
this.translate.getLangs().includes(langParam)
```

as I do not think you can inject services in UrlMatcher